# How to make finite part integral (integral with a horizontal dash) in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I need to make an integral that looks like this:

[image: pickture of integral]

or on a real world example like this:

[image]

in LaTeX?
I couldn't find any special integral symbols in latex except `\oint`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

you could use:

https://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math/index.html

or

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

or

https://www.mathcha.io/editor

to use the last one just write \ then choose inline-math then write \ again. you can see the drawing option and you can get the latex code.

Answer (score 2):

With http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html I get the message back that a possible suitable symbol is `fint` from the `esint` package (Extended set of integrals for Computer Modern) the bar is not horizontal but slightly upwards.